# error C2088: '+=': illegal for union on visual studio with c

Tags: c, structure, union

Hi I am getting error C2088: '+=': illegal for union error on visual studio ...
for 
same code working properly on gcc.
Could you please let me know the solution to fix this issue in c with visual studio.

```
typedef union {
    float sm[8];
} Su;


typedef union {
    Su v;
    float bm[8];
} Bu;

int main() {
    Bu A1, A2;

    A2.v.sm[0] = 12.5;

    // .... some assignments here 

    A1.v += A2.v;     //      <<<<<<<<<<<< error here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile on gcc, nor should it.

Comment: same code working fine in gcc in linux ... when i port same code to visual studio on windows having this issue.

Comment: *same code working fine in gcc in linux* - [I find this really hard to believe](https://godbolt.org/z/n3zNeM).

Comment: What is `A1.v += A2.v;` even supposed to mean? What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: Voting to close this as "cannot be reproduced" since it doesn't compile at all on gcc or any other C compiler.

Comment: regarding: `A1.v += A2.v;`  This is trying to add one array of floats to another array of floats.  That does not work in C. So, of course it does not compile.

Answer (score 2):

The `v` member of `A1` and `A2` is a union type with a single array member `sm`, and `+=` is not defined for union types.  If you want to add the values of `A2.v.sm` to the values of `A1.v.sm`, then you’ll need to use a loop:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
  A1.v.sm[i] += A2.v.sm[i];
```

**Edit**

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.5.16.2 Compound assignment**
> **Constraints**
> 1     For the operators **`+=`** and **`-=`** only, either the left operand shall be an atomic, qualified, or
> unqualified pointer to a complete object type, and the right shall have integer type; or the
> left operand shall have atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right
> shall have arithmetic type.